# How to achieve a shadowed shape behind a semi opaque surface?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shadows

Imagine a white paper, a shape behind it, and behind the shape a source of light, like a candle. I want to achieve the shadow effect you perceive looking at the white paper. How to do this in photoshop?

Comment: Hi Untore, welcome to GD! Like Boblet said, what have you tried? Could you post some images or examples to show us where you are having difficulty.

Comment: I thnk what s/he is refering to is shadow puppetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm right in assuming what you're looking for is a similar effect of shadow puppetry, then you can achieve this in Photoshop using multiple layers:

I started with a blank colored background
[image]

I added a subtle vignette with a radial gradient
[image]

I thenj added my silhouette
[image]

I added another on top, enlarged it and gave it a gausian blur and reduced the opacity (You can move this one around to change where the light source is)
[image]

Finally, I changed the colors of the blured image to better mimic a shadow
[image: Finished image]